# IF statements and concatenation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Excel information]

If you can see the info I have in the spreadsheet, my question might make more sense. What I'm trying to do is set up a formula so that if the value in Column C =3, then add "-P10$A" to the end of the sample number in Column A. Similarly if the value in Column C =9, add "-M10$A" or C=7, add "-R10$A". If the value in column C is anything else other than 3,9,or 7, then add "-M10$A". I hope that isn't too confusing, I'm novice when it comes to excel formulas and coding. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the formula I'm using right now.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,"-P10$A",IF(C2="","",))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested IF:

```
=A2 & IF(C2=3,"-P10$A",IF(C2=7,"-R10$A","-M10$A"))
```

Comment: WOW! that was amazingly fast. Thank you so much for you help.